# What is the use of perl folder in xampp why it is included in xampp?

Tags: perl, xampp

As we know that xampp is for web development but what is the use of perl folder in xampp? Why perl folder is included in xampp? I am beginner and have no idea about the perl folder but i know perl is a programming language.

Can anyone tell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> XAMPP is a completely free, easy to install Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP, and **Perl**. The XAMPP open source package has been set up to be incredibly easy to install and to use.

— https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

The Perl folder contains files needed to run server-side code written in Perl.

Comment: Actually the AMPP in XAMPP is for **A**pache, **M**ariaDB, **P**HP, and **P**erl. Dunno what the X is for, though.

Comment: @PerlDuck: [*X as an ideographic letter referring to cross‑platform*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP#Etymology)

Comment: You mean perl code(if any) that we place on the server is handled by the files placed in the perl folder ? You mean perl file contains a perl code executor which handles and runs perl code on the server ?

Comment: @MummyDaddy Exactly. And we usually call that “perl code executor” the _Perl interpreter_. The language is called _Perl_ and the program that runs the scripts written in _Perl_ is called _perl_.